# Pointer is NULL after returning from a function

Tags: c++, function, pointers

I send int*** to a function and the function does it job, but when I try to use the pointer in outside after the function, it is NULL. Here is the function:

```
void pointerSort2(int* arr, unsigned int size, char ascend_flag, int*** pointers)
{
    int  i, j, *temp;
    int** sort=new int*[size];

    for (i=0;i<size;i++)
        sort[i]=&arr[i];                                                     

    if (ascend_flag==true)
    {
        for (i=0;i<size-1;i++)
        { 
            for(j=0; j<size-1-i;j++)
            {
                if (*sort[j]>*sort[j+1])
                {
                    temp=sort[j];
                    sort[j]=sort[j+1];
                    sort[j+1]=temp;
                }
        }
    }

    pointers=&sort;
}
```

When I try to use it after, the pointer is "0x000000 (???)"

Comment: Wow. Looking at the code only, I would almost assume this was C code except for the `new`.

Comment: `std::vector`? `std::sort`? References? If you used these, you wouldn't have problems like this.

Comment: `pointers = &sort` should possibly be `*pointers = sort`.

Answer (score 7):

The function parameter `int*** pointers` is a local variable of the function. This variable will be destroyed after exiting the function.

I think that instead of line

```
pointers=&sort;
```

there should be

```
*pointers = sort;
```

Answer (score 4):

First of, if this is not for an assignment, containers and algorithms already exist that will do all of this for you:

Containers:  `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::deque`
Sort Algorithm: `std::sort`

Most of your problems go away simply by using the standard library templates.

That aside, you also do not appear to have a good understanding of the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference as well as pointer semantics.

**Passing an `int***` to a function that takes an `int***`**

If you declare a function as

```
void func(int i);
```

And call it:

```
int j = 0;
func(j);
```

Nothing that `func` does to the `i` parameter is reflected in `j`.  A *copy* of `j` is passed to `func`.  If you wanted to store any changes `func` made to the `i` parameter, you would need to either use a reference or a pointer:

```
void func(int& i);
// or
void func(int* pI); // requires you to call it via func(&j)
```

The same goes for your current code:

You've declared your sort function as follows

```
void pointerSort2(..., int*** pointers);
```

If you were to call it like so

```
int*** myPointer = NULL;
pointerSort2(..., myPointer);
```

You are passing it by value.  This will copy the value of the pointer (currently `NULL`) into the function's local variable `pointers`.  When the function returns, `myPointer` is unchanged.  If your goal is to keep the changed value in `myPointer`, you need to either pass-by-reference or pass a pointer to your `int***` (NOTE:  this level of indirection is already a code smell!)  The potential solutions to this would be:

```
void pointerSort2(..., int***& pointers);
// or
void pointerSort2(..., int**** pointers);
```

Which would allow you to call the function in these ways (respectively):

```
int*** myPointer = NULL;
pointerSort2(..., myPointer);
// or
pointerSort2(..., &myPointer);
```

For the first version, you would set the value of `pointers` to the value of `sort` like this:

```
pointers = sort;
```

Since `pointers` is a reference (an alias) to `myPointer`, the value of `myPointer` is changed.

For the second version, you would set the value of `pointers` to the value of `sort` like this:

```
*pointers = sort;
```

Since `pointers` is a pointer to the location of `myPointer`, you are setting the actual value of `myPointer`.

Note that in both cases, you are setting the value to `sort` (the value of the pointer), **not** `&sort` (the address of the pointer).

**Side Note**

`bool` is a type that is used for `true` and `false` values.  Your `ascend_flag` parameter would be better served as a `bool` instead of a `char`.

Answer (score 1):

#### The following line:

```
pointers = &sort;
```

is causing your problem. `sort` is a pointer to a pointer. Being so, it is a variable that is created inside the local scope of the function.

It gets destroyed when the function exits.

Try removing the `&`

We want to go to the local pointers variable, find what it's pointing to, and change that value.
pointers is not being passed by reference, it, like any other parameter, is copied and destroyed per each runtime function call on the stack.

```
*pointers = sort;
```